# CDN with Django for user upload file

Tags: django, cdn

I have been reading CDN with Django. Currently I am planning to use CDN to store my static file. However, I would like to store user uploaded images/videos on CDN too.

I am new to web development so is it a right choice to use CDN for user media? If not, what's better choice for storing user upload files?

Thanks.

Comment: CDNs are great. 
The first kind of static files are things like jquery and bootstrap css. You should google `jquery CDN` and they will give you the link. Your custom files like custom icons, sure why not. For developmnet purpose, try not to.http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8112/whats-the-best-free-cdn-service-available